# XMPP: Similarity between group / MUC (groupchat)

Tags: xmpp, asmack

I am confused with similarities of group & MUC(groupchat).

To do chat between more than 1 user, i feel both creating group with more than 1 member is similar to creating MUC with more than 1 member.

I came up with following logic to create MUC room:

1> User mike@example.org creates a group say, 'song'.

2> Users, dara@example.org and kevin@example.org are also added to 'song'.

3> I consider a service song@conference.example.org running.

4>I create MUC with above service as the MUC room name.

5>I successfully see messages exchanged between mike,dara,kevin via the room 'song'.

This is how i bought in 2 concepts into one to create MUC room.

I need an expert opinion on this.

thanks

Comment: Please define 'Group'.

Comment: @Flow, Group refers to roster groups in XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you call group, but I think in the context of XMPP, you may be referring to [roster groups](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html#createGroup(java.lang.String)). Roster groups are only used to group contact in your contact list. They are not related to message broadcast.

Multi User Chat (MUC) rooms are used to chat with several people involved. The two concepts are not related.
Conclusion: Indeed, in XMPP, the most common way to chat with several people is indeed to invite them in a MUC room.